# How to fix "Relationship entity cannot have a missing start or end node" when I add rich relationship between nodes?

Tags: java, kotlin, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using Java Neo4j OGM in my Kotlin application. I have to add a `isUnit` relation between two nodes (`Query` and `Unit`). It is a rich relationship entity `IsUnit` with property `value`. Why am I getting `Relationship entity ogm.relationships.IsUnit@121de1de cannot have a missing start or end node` error on saving?

Neo4j version: 3.5.3 (enterprise)
OGM version: 3.1.2

Query.kt:

```
package ogm.nodes

import ...

@NodeEntity
class Query() {
    <...>

    @Relationship(type = RelationType.IS_UNIT, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    var units: MutableSet<IsUnit> = mutableSetOf()

    <...>
}
```

Unit.kt:

```
package ogm.nodes

import ...

@NodeEntity
class Unit() {
    <...>

    @JsonIgnore
    @Relationship(type = RelationType.IS_UNIT, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    var query: IsUnit? = null

    <...>
}
```

IsUnit.kt:

```
package ogm.relationships

import ...

@RelationshipEntity(type = RelationType.IS_UNIT)
class IsUnit() {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private var id: Long? = null
    fun getId(): Long? = id

    var uuid: String? = null
    var value: Float? = null

    @StartNode
    var rate: Rate? = null
    @StartNode
    var query: Query? = null
    @EndNode
    var unit: Unit? = null
}
```

Logic:

```
val unit = session.loadAll(
    Unit::class.java,
    Filter("uuid", ComparisonOperator.EQUALS, uuid),
    0
).first()

val isUnit = IsMUnit()
isUnit.query = query
isUnit.unit = unit
isUnit.value = v

query.units.add(isUnit)
unit.query = isUnit

session.save(query, 1)
```

I expect that new relationship between existing nodes will be created.
But I got:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Relationship entity ogm.relationships.IsMeasureUnit@121de1de cannot have a missing start or end node
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.haveRelationEndsChanged(EntityGraphMapper.java:546)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.getRelationshipBuilder(EntityGraphMapper.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:464)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:389)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:237)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:131)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:474)
    at queryProcessor.QueryProcessor.changeQuery(QueryProcessor.kt:117)
    at queryProcessor.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.kt:24)
    at com.pathfind.ApplicationKt$module$5$3.invokeSuspend(Application.kt:74)
...
```

I tried different depth of `sessiuon.save()` method, but it still doesn't work.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that rich relationship entities can have only one @StartNode and @EndNode. 
Is it true? What if I need same relations between different node types? Have I to duplicate code?